# Python Calculation GUI error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding a python gui that does a calculation on 2 hex inputs then outputs calculation to text boxes.this is the error I am getting I have tried putting (int) with the (int(Text.get)) but it will not work still get same error.I am using python 2.7.13.

```
File "C:\Users\oaeel\Desktop\guialg.py", line 5, in calculate
Seed = (a1 << 8 | a2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

---

```
from Tkinter import *

def calculate():
    Seed = (a1 << 8 | a2)
    num1 = Seed
    num2 = Seed >> 8 & 255
    num3 = Seed & 255
    num4 = e2.insert
    num5 = e6.insert
    print(num4)
    print(num5)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("218x200")

b1 = Button(text="calculate seed", command=calculate)
b1.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10)

f1 = LabelFrame(text="Seed")
f1.configure(width=1, height=1)
f1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

f2 = LabelFrame(text="Key")
f2.configure(width=1, height=1)
f2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

e1 = Entry(f1, width=2)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

e2 = Text(f2, width=2, height=1)
e2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


e5 = Entry(f1, width=2)
e5.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

e6 = Text(f2, width=2, height=1)
e6.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

a1 = (e1.get())
a2 = (e5.get())



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see `int(Text.get)` anywhere. Your current code fails presumably because `get` returns a string.

Comment: I removed it from a1 = (int(e1.get()) and a2 = (int(e1.get()) it did not work.Added "tuple" to the same error.

Comment: What's the exact error when using `int`?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: If that's the exact error, your problem is that `get` is returning an empty string, which obviously can't be parsed as an int. I've never used `tkinter`, but are you sure `get` is the right method to be using here? And are you sure the right element contains the text?

Comment: I added it to the function and it works now.

Comment: When you tested it the first time, you must have had the elements backwards or something. Really, you should check for bad input before using it. You have no idea what the user will enter (or not enter).